# How to have google sheets autocomplete some aspects of a function, but keep others the same

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to be able to replicate these function on a large scale:

```
=INDEX(List1!A1:G21, MATCH(F2, List1!A1:A21), MATCH(E2, List1!B1:F1)+1)
```

but I need these aspects to stay the same:

```
A1:G21
A1:A21
B1:F1
```

and this to change according to their position in the sheet:

```
F2:E2
```

I also need this function:

```
=INDEX(List1!A1:G21, MATCH(F2, List1!A1:A21), 7)
```

and need to change this value according to is position:

```
F2
```

but need this to stay the same:

```
A1:G21
A1:A21
7
```

I had tried using Google's autocomplete, but it obviously scales all the value in accordance to its position and since I am very new to sheets, I haven't a clue on what I could do. I tried writing a js function, but my experience in js is little and I couldn't keep up.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an $ before the aspect you want fixated:

$A$1 would never move

$A1 would be always in Column 1 and change its number

A$1 would only move the column but not the row